# vb.net - How to get webbrowser InnerHtml under multithread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I use `SetApartmentState` in webbrowser:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim th As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Task_A)
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    th.Start()        
End Sub

Public Sub Task_A()
    Dim frmBuild = New NewForm() 
    Dim WebBrowser1 = New WebBrowser()
    Application.Run(frmBuild)
    frmBuild.Controls.Add(WebBrowser1)
    WebBrowser1.CreateControl()
End Sub

Private Delegate Function GetInnerHTMLCallBack() As String        
Private Function GetInnerHTML() As String
    If WebBrowser1.InvokeRequired Then
        Return CStr(WebBrowser1.Invoke(New GetInnerHTMLCallBack(AddressOf GetInnerHTML)))
    Else
        Return WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml
    End If
End Function

Dim innerHTML As String = GetInnerHTML()  
frmMain.textbox1.text=innerHTML
Dim docs As mshtml.HTMLDocument = WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument
```

I get nothing, how can I get or set string in cross threading?
I am very poor in multi-threading.

Comment: There's a way to make a WebBrowser control work in a thread other than the Main UI thread. But the WB really, really doesn't like it and It's a possible source of all kind of mis-behaviours if you don't handle it very very carefully. Why do you need this? The WB operations are already asynchronous.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. _Why_ are you trying to do this? What are you trying to achieve? You generally should try to access the UI as little as possible from a background thread.

Comment: I want use the webbrosewer on Background, I try use it on BackgroundWorker in new form, but when loading website , it cause main form suspended about 5 seconds.

Comment: Just move your WebBrowser out of the client area of your Form (negative Location values). Forget about threading.

Comment: After finish loading website, the textbox in the main form lost focus.

Comment: What .Net Framework version are you using? I remember that the WebBrowser control stole the focus. But it was years ago. Anyway, you could just use `[Control].Focus()` in the `DocumentCompleted` event to move/restore the Focus to some other control. Forget about threading :)